# Is there a way to programmatically find which account has been locked out in django-axes?

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I would like to check which accounts have been locked out in django-axes. I know this can be done in admin site, but can I get this in a view.py as well?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/8_reference.html

Comment: I did. It is not what I was looking for. However, I found a working solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer in order to help anyone else who may have the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can actually access django-axes just like any other model object. .objects.all() and then you can do some calculations with that.

Answer (score 1):

To see a list of users that are locked you can do the following

```
from axes.models import AccessAttempt
AccessAttempt.objects.all().values_list('username', flat=True)
```

Comment: This isn't that simple. You should consider only users that have exceeded the threshold, both for attempts count and cooloff_time (if set).

`from axes.attempts import get_cool_off_threshold`
`from django.conf import settings`
`failure_limit=settings.AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT`
`cooloff = get_cool_off_threshold()`
`lock_out_users = AccesAttempt.objects.filter(attempt_time__gte=cooloff, failures_since_start__gte=failure_limit).values_list('username', flat=True)`

Comment: To my knowledge an AccessAttempt object will only be created if the user gets locked out so should be no need to filter by anything else but I could be wrong

Comment: That's not the case. With default axes configuration, the user is locked out when the Sum of his AccessAttempts exceeds (or equals) the limit (3 by default).

Here is the check from source code: https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/blob/1d23bab33bb8b4dbb310a18b8bcc1bd61366a840/axes/handlers/database.py#L225
If you dive deeper what those functions are doing, you'll find what i've explained.

Comment: Here is the 'get_failures' source: https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/blob/1d23bab33bb8b4dbb310a18b8bcc1bd61366a840/axes/handlers/database.py#L104, the 'get_failures_limit' (right hand side of equation) just returns the value of AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT setting (which is 3 by default).

Comment: @Elembivios oh I'm not saying that the user isn't locked out after 3 attempts, just that the AccessAttempt object isn't created until there has been 3 failed login attempts. Like if you clear all AccessAttempt objects and fail to log in, there will still be no objects until the 3rd failed attempt. So there is no reason to filter by attempt_time__gte=cool off and failures_since_start__gte=failure limit as you can't have an object created with less than that

Comment: Well I think you're wrong and I guess I can't change your mind, so i'll just post my own answer..

Comment: @Elembivios apologies if my response upset you, wasn't my intention. Just wanted to share my findings. For me I don't need to add in those filters to get the result the OP is referring to.

Comment: Np i'm not mad. The reason I was bothering you is your answer was closest to being correct. If it works for you that great, but just try one thing. Check what your AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT setting is set to (i'm guessing 3) and:
1.) Do an invalid login once (or < times than AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT)
2.) Check what your code above returns (is locked or not) via shell or smthing
3.) Try to login again, this time with same username and valid password (can you login?)

In my case the code above returns that i'm locked, but I can still log in.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my answer because the accepted answer is too vague. "*do some calculations with that*" just doesn't cut if for me. Using axes helper functions is also not acceptable since they are ment to be used for current request (the user that is currently trying to log in). Only checking if AccessAttempt objects exist for a user is also not correct.

AccessAttempt objects are used for counting how many invalid attempts have been made by an unique username and ip_address (not by a user!). Every AccessAttempt is unique for a combination of username and ip_address and has a field 'failures_since_start' that counts the number of failed login attempts.

**That being said.. with default [AXES configuration](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_configuration.html) (blocking by ip_address) there is really no reliable way of knowing if a user is locked.** For example: user could lock his ip address on one pc, but still be able to login on the other pc; or he could be misstyping his username and be still locked out (by ip_adrress), but his User is not really locked out, only the ip, etc.

**However, with AXES configuration set to block only on username, there IS a way of knowing if a User is locked out and here is how:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Sum, Case, When, Value, BooleanField
from axes.models import AccessAttempt

# Create a subquery for counting number of login failures per username
login_failures_count = AccessAttempt.objects.filter(
    username = OuterRef("username")
).order_by("username").values("username").annotate(
    login_failures_count = Sum("failures_since_start")
).values("login_failures_count")

# Annotate 'is_locked' and 'login_failures_count' to users query
users = User.objects.all().annotate(
    login_failures_count = Subquery(login_failures_count)
).annotate(
    is_locked = Case(
        When(
            login_failures_count__gte = settings.AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT,
            then = Value(True)
        ),
        default = Value(False),
        output_field = BooleanField()
    )
)

# Get only locked out users
locked_users = users.filter(is_locked=True)

# Or print users and if they are locked
for user in users:
    print(f"Username: {user.username}, Is locked: {user.is_locked}")
```

Note: this solution heavily depends on your [AXES configuration](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_configuration.html). For example, if you have AXES_COOLOFF_TIME set, you should change subquery to:

```
from axes.attempts import get_cool_off_threshold

AccessAttempt.objects.filter(
    username = OuterRef("username"),
    attempt_time__gte = get_cool_off_threshold()
).orde...
```

Answer (score -1):

The Axes documentation describes the [`AxesBaseHandler.is_locked`](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/8_reference.html#axes.handlers.base.AxesBaseHandler.is_locked) method.

You can find its definition [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/blob/5.26.0/axes/handlers/base.py#L123-L134).

I use `is_locked` in my code base - it takes a `request` and `credentials`, so it may not seem like the most convenient way to detect whether a user is locked out, but lock-out is determined not only by attempts, but can be configured based on ip-addr, cooldown period, etc.

Comment: I'm almost certain that this method is for checking if the current Request and User is locked out.